# Button is not opening a new screen

Tags: android

Don't know what else really to add. When I press the button, which should open a new screen, nothing happens.

Also, EditText is not saving any of the input after returning to the MainActivity screen.

Order of code:
MainActivity
NewScreenActivity
Manifest.xml
(Didn't include xml of each activity but can if it's necessary)

Both activities are in the same package.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userText;
    Button buttonToNewScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userText);
        buttonToNewScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToNewScreen);
        userText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = userText.getText().toString();
                Intent toNewScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewScreenActivity.class);
                toNewScreen.putExtra("input", input);
                startActivity(toNewScreen);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String userInput;
    EditText output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_screen);
        Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
        userInput = thisIntent.getStringExtra("input");
        output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);
        output.setText(userInput);

    }
}
```

---

(generate by Android Studio)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intri.firstexample">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NewScreenActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: walk away, and the come back to your code in 20 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buttonToNewScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToNewScreen);
userText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = userText.getText().toString();
                Intent toNewScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewScreenActivity.class);
                toNewScreen.putExtra("input", input);
                startActivity(toNewScreen);
            }
        });
```

Instead of `userText` (which is an `EditText`) set onClickListener to `buttonToNewScreen`.

Comment: @user2465510 You are welcome. If solved, please accept my answer, thanks.